# Visual Studio debug - dump array to file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, native

I attached a Visual Studio 2015 debugger to a process and want to dump a specific memory section to a file (unsigned char array, contains binary image data). Is something like that possible?

edit: I dumped the array using HxD (Hex editor). Searched for the start of the array (by searching a long sequence of the start of the array) and selected the array length, seems kind of hacky tho.

Comment: As an aside you may want to look at WinDbg the [`.writemem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566176(v=vs.85).aspx) cmd is designed specifically for this

Comment: @EdChum is WinDbg installed alongside with VS?

Comment: No, you either install the platform SDK or you can just get it from here: http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/. Basically install it, attach, debug as normal then call `.writemem` with path and memory range.

Comment: Ok, will have a look at this. Would be really nice to have a option to dump memory inside VS tho, as I'm already at the exact memory location in memory view.

Answer (score -1):

It is.

When the debugger has stopped at an exception or at a breakpoint, click Debug and choose Save Dump As...

In the Save as type list, you can select Minidump or Minidump with Heap (the default).

Comment: I only want a specific memory (a 4MB array) to be dumped, I already have the heap dump